# Mix of query and form params in REST service?

Tags: rest

We have a REST API which, for certain operations, we provide the option of asynchronous requests. For async requests, the service will return immediately with a token which can be used to query for completion, while for synchronous requests, the response will not be returned until the operation completes.

The current design for this looks something like this:

URL: `PUT /api/orders/1234?async=true`

Request Body: `customerName=My Company&city=Dallas`

Intuitively, it seems wrong to mix query and form params like this, however the query param (async) is providing options to the service call and not an attribute of the resource. That was the primary reason we did not include it in the request body.

Does this approach seem like a good design, or is there a better more "REST-y" way to accomplish the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Prefer header is designed to do exactly what you are trying to do.  See the [spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-snell-http-prefer-18).

Comment: From the draft: "Expires: July 11, 2013". So this header is not part of HTTP.

Comment: @Tichodroma  The spec has been approved and is working its way through IETF due process. http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-snell-http-prefer/history/  The web works due to a wide range of interoperating specs.  Media types are not "part of HTTP".  Many of the HTTP methods are not defined by the HTTP spec (e.g. PATCH). Same goes for response codes. That's how it is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1):

An URL like this

```
POST /api/orders/1234?async=true
```

is not RESTful. Why `POST`? This looks like RPC over HTTP.

What are your resources? If there is some computation involved, model the *computation* as resources. `POST` to a collection of compuations to create a new one. Receive a `Location` header for the result of the computation.

```
POST /api/orders

custoerName=My Company
city=Dallas
```

This could return a response like:

```
201 Created
Location: /api/orders/1234
```

Then the client could `GET` the result:

```
GET /api/orders/1234
```

And the server would respond:

```
200 OK

Some result body.
```

**How to make this asynchronouse?**

You write:

> however the query param (async) is providing options to the service call and not an attribute of the resource

This is plain wrong. *Everything* that is in the URI is used to *identify* the resource. REST is not about calling methods with parameters.

I recommend to *always* use the two-step-approach described above when modeling compuations/transactions/shopping carts as resources. Create it, retrieve it.

Comment: You're correct, this should have been a "PUT" (update) in the scenario I was trying to describe. I'll edit the original question to clarify. However, the gist of the question was how to let the client specify whether they want to wait for the operation to complete or not.

Comment: The client waits or he doesn't wait. That's totally up to him. In both cases the server should always respond to a `GET` request with a response that describes the current server state of the resource.